# Page number automatically resets 1 after switching pages with angular

Tags: angular, pagination, ngx-pagination

I don't know why pageNumber in bookParams auto reset to 1 after I changed the page from 1 to 2.

```
export class BookListComponent implements OnInit {
  books: Book[];
  bookParams: BookParams;
  pagination: Pagination;
  constructor(private bookService: BookService, private accountService: AccountService) {
    accountService.currentUser$.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(user => {
      this.bookParams = new BookParams(user);
      console.log("contructor " + this.bookParams.pageNumber);
    })
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    let a = this.bookParams;
    this.loadBooks();
  }

  loadBooks() {
    console.log("loadBooks" + this.bookParams.pageNumber);
    this.bookService.getBooks(this.bookParams).subscribe(response => {
        this.books = response.result;
        this.pagination = response.pagination;
        this.pagination.currentPage = 1;
    })
  }
  pageChanged(event: any) {
    console.log("PageChange "+event.page);
    this.bookParams.pageNumber = event.page;
    this.loadBooks();
  }
}
```

**BookParams.ts**

```
export class BookParams {
    pageSize = 8;
    pageNumber = 1;
}
```

[image]

pic after I click change page

[image]

Comment: Why do you fetch seemingly the same set of books each time the page is changed?

Answer (score 1):

Your `pageChanged` function calls your `loadBooks` function, which in turn has this line:

```
this.pagination.currentPage = 1;
```

Hence, it will be pointing to first page after every page change (that is assuming changing pages calls the `pageChanged` function - we don't have enough information with what you posted.

Comment: Thanks, I deleted this code and it worked. I followed a course in the internet but they still use `this.pagination.currentPage = 1;` and your it still works, its very confuse